# Data transfers (from/to server vs from/to client) in non-browser distributed applications

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

So we have command line scripts (written in Python) that sit on customer machines and send us data in CSV after every 24 hours. Now we are at a point that we actually want to be able to tell the clients to send us data any time. Almost all of the customers are on MS Windows machines and requirement is that we can install very little software on the customer machines (and most people cannot even log on to customer machines, only few people can).

I'm not actually sure as to how to best solve this problem. May be following are three possible ways (but looking for better)

1. We make a daemon in Python and install it on customer machine.
   Daemon talks to our servers and we send back configuration
   information. In that configuration information we send back the
   "sleep duration". So daemon sends us the data and then goes to sleep
   for number of seconds defined in "sleep duration" variable. Once the
   limit is over, daemon pings us and again we send back the
   configuration information. Rinse and repeat.
2. We install a script on customer machine and it runs every hour. At
       our end, we've stored how often a customer should send us data (24
       hours, 12 hours, and etc) and when script talks to us we determine
       how much time has passed and if it is time that script should be
       sending us data? If it's time, then we tell the script to send us
       data.
3. We install a very small server-side (Django or Flask) application
       and it runs on customer machines. Whenever we want data we send a
       request to customer machine and our small server-side application
       serves us. For that may be we will ask our customers to reserve a
       port for us (not sure how many customers will actually allow this)

I'm sure there are better ways possible. Can you kindly let me which of the above methods are most suitable? Or please let me know if there exists a better way.

I really appreciate all insights, thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 may not work.  Most people have their machines behind a 
fire-wall or router which does NAT.  In such a scenario, a server that is listening for a request to come in would not typically be accessible from the public internet.

If they have static IP addresses and if the server is accessible from the public internet, then port scanners would detect it and potentially attempt to do undesirable things.  You really do not someone hacking into your customer systems and wrecking havoc on them. Please avoid this option if possible.

However, it is safe to have a server on a customer system as long as it is the one logging into your server and sending data.

A better solution would be to have an app that is continuously
feeding data to your server as it is generated.  Is is relatively
easy to do an equivalent of

```
    tail -f csv_file | send_data_home
```

where send_data_home is program running on your customer's system.
This way there is minimal impact.  The csv file creation is not
affected. The send_data_home logs into your server and sends
data as it is generated.